# How to detect if font size has increased in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, browser

I have a problem with blocks in the site if the user increases the font size in the settings of the browser. How can I detect it, to solve the problem via JavaScript?

[image: Some image of the problem]

Comment: That image appears to show the font settings of the browser, which is great, but not really anything to do with the problem at hand. Also, do note that there is a [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/), although I must admit I don't know if that is Russian or not :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unformatted text, you could use `Window.getComputedStyle()`, passing in some element, and then check the text/font size properties.

Check out Mozilla's documentation for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle